# Correct sums with dividing sums, countering rounding errors

Tags: php, divide, rounding-error

*Web app coded in PHP with a MySQL database.*

I have a system which calculates different costs for a number of people when splitting a cost. For example **Person A** buys something for 10 and **Persons B, C, and D** should split the cost.

The system should therefor register a positive record for **person A** of 10 and negative records of 10/3 for **B, C and D.**

However, when this is done; **B, C and D** all have -3.33 after rounding. Which of course **doesn't add up** to the total of 10. What's the best way of going about this problem? An optimal solution would randomise what person get's the slightly bigger cost as well.

One possible solution is if I just let the last person's debt be `10 - (A + B)`, but then there's a problem if **four persons** split a cost of for example 13.34. The different parts would then be 3.34, 3.34, 3.34 and 3.32, whereas the optimal split would be 3.34, 3.34, 3.33, 3.33.

Some might argue that with **sufficient decimals** this is only a problem when having vast amounts of rows. But in an economical system I think it's important to have a **fail-safe** system even from the start. It needs to be **scalable**, and can't have even the slightest error. *Unfairness* is alright, just not errors.

*Similar problem: [sum divided values problem (dealing with rounding error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784864/sum-divided-values-problem-dealing-with-rounding-error)*

Comment: " Unfairness is alright, just not errors." - love it

Comment: I think I would find the two closest dividing values, then toggle between the two as they are assigned.  Then figure out what to do with the (potential) last odd value.

Comment: This is how every question should look :). Very well described. +1 from me.

Comment: With money involved, I think fairness ends up always being important--if your system consistently overcharges a certain class of users (based on e.g. ID number, registration date, alphabetized names, or however else your database sorts records), there's some potential for a class action. One fair approach would be to randomly pick a user to charge from the list of users not yet charged, each time you calculate a charge amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/nQakD/ .

Used jQuery as example, but if you know PHP you should be able to easily convert it to PHP. If you need also php code, tell me, I will wrote it for you.

I'll paste the code here also -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var price = 17.48, people = 4, payment = (price/people).toFixed(2), count=0;
    var payments = [];
    for(i = 0; i < people; i++) {
       payments.push(payment);   
    }

    if(payment*people != price) {
        var currentPayment = payment*people;

        $(payments).each(function() {
            if(currentPayment < price) {
                currentPayment = (currentPayment-this).toFixed(2);
                var newPayment = parseFloat(this)+0.01;
                payments[count] = newPayment.toFixed(2);
                currentPayment = parseFloat(currentPayment)+parseFloat(newPayment);
            }
            else if(currentPayment > price) {
                currentPayment = (currentPayment-this).toFixed(2);
                var newPayment = parseFloat(this)-0.01;
                payments[count] = newPayment.toFixed(2);
                currentPayment = parseFloat(currentPayment)+parseFloat(newPayment);
            }
            count++;
        });   

    }  
    $(payments).each(function() {
        $("#result").append("<b>"+this+"</b><br/>");
    });       
});​
```

**EDIT:**

And here is working php code -

```
$price = 13.34;
$people = 4;
$payment = (float)$price/$people;
$payment = 0.01 * (int)($payment*100);
$count = 0;
$payments = Array();
for($i = 0; $i < $people; $i++) {
    array_push($payments, $payment);
}
if($payment*$people != $price) {
    $currentPayment = $payment*$people;
    foreach($payments as $pay) {
        if($currentPayment < $price) {
            $currentPayment = $currentPayment-$pay;
            $currentPayment = 0.01 * (int)($currentPayment*100);               
            $newPayment = (float)$pay+0.01;
            $newPayment = 0.01 * (int)($newPayment*100);
            $payments[$count] = $newPayment;
            $currentPayment = (float)$currentPayment+$newPayment;
        }
        else if($currentPayment > $price) {
            $currentPayment = $currentPayment-$pay;
            $currentPayment = 0.01 * (int)($currentPayment*100);               
            $newPayment = (float)$pay-0.01;
            $newPayment = 0.01 * (int)($newPayment*100);
            $payments[$count] = $newPayment;
            $currentPayment = (float)$currentPayment+$newPayment;
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
foreach($payments as $payed) {
    echo '<b>'.$payed.'</b><br />';
}​​​
```

**EDIT 2:**

This should fix the js issue - http://jsfiddle.net/nQakD/ updated code above also.

**EDIT 3:**

Edited PHP code and JS code so it does work for all examples - http://jsfiddle.net/nQakD/ .

Comment: Thank you very much! A few questions though: 

**1.** when casting $payment as an int, does it result in 3.33 or 3.34, ie. rounded or not?

**2.** When trying different values in your wonderful js-script I can get values that are not rounded to two decimals. Should I do a similar int-cast somewhere in the if-statement?

Comment: 1) It will result in 3.33. 2) Can you give me some examples?

Comment: For example if you set the price to 13.37.

Comment: Updated example should fix it.

Comment: Yes, but broke something new. 17.42 doesn't add up to 17.42. Trying to locate error.

Comment: Will have a look on it when I'll get home.

Comment: The error occurs when the initial payment is larger than average. Then it breaks due to 0.01 being **added** every time instead of adjusted.

Comment: Modified it so it should be right now, is there a more optimised way of doing it to avoid redundancy? http://jsfiddle.net/FvtKa/

Comment: replace second if with else if, so it doesn't execute both if statements. Will reduce loading time.

Comment: Did you update the PHP to your latest version of the JS as well? Cant't really tell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a new "rounding balance" up for every user. If it was 10 to be split three ways, then each user would pay 3.34. Each user would also have 2/3 of a cent to their rounding balance. (this would have to be stored as text I presume) .

Next time the same thing happens, check the rounding balance.. They have 2/3 of a cent, so now you can take one third off (so they now have 1/3 of a cent in the rounding balance ) and only charge 3.33 .